Less verbose execution of a backup file with psql (only show actual errors and warnings)
How to make psql less verbose when I restore an SQL backup file? I want Postgres to only show me errors and maybe notices, nothing else.
So I want to see errors like this:
ERROR:  relation "testing" does not exist
LINE 1: select * from testing
                      ^

I do not want things like that:
SET
SET
SET
SET
SET
 set_config
------------

(1 row)

SET
SET
SET
SET
SET
SET

I need a more sane ;) version of this:
psql -U postgres -d $dbName -f /tmp/${backupFile} 2>&1 \
| grep -vE 'CREATE SCHEMA|DROP TABLE|CREATE TABLE|ALTER TABLE|SET|set_config|------------|\([0-9]+ rows?\)'


psql -U postgres -d $dbName -f /tmp/${backupFile} > output_file.txt ? As in psql -d postgres -U postgres -f farm_app_16.sql > output_file.txt psql:farm_app_16.sql:19: ERROR:  database "farm_db" does not exist

Added an example error I want to see.

Have you tried what I suggested?

The -q does make psql quieter, but that's not quite what you are after, you want to change the level of message that makes it to your screen.
export PGOPTIONS='-c client_min_messages=WARNING'
psql ...

That should remove all the SET but will show any query results you may generate in the script.
